# How to transform a JSON file that has 1 'header' row followed by 'data' rows? - (use jq?)

Tags: python, json, pandas, jq

I have a JSON file, like this:

```
{
   "data" : [
     { "values" : [ "ColumnHeader1", "ColumnHeader2", "ColumnHeader3" ]},
     { "values" : [ "Row1Column1", "Row1Column2", "Row1Column3" ]},
     { "values" : [ "Row2Column1", "Row2Column2", "Row2Column3" ]}
  ]
}
```

I want to transform it, to be like this:

```
{
   data: [
     { "ColumnHeader1" : "Row1Value1", "ColumnHeader2": "Row1Value2", "ColumnHeader3" : "Row1Value3" },
     { "ColumnHeader1" : "Row2Value1", "ColumnHeader2": "Row2Value2", "ColumnHeader3" : "Row2Value3" }
  ]
}
```

I did write a Python script for that - but I wonder could something clever be done via `jq` or `pandas` ? (or some other Unix tool or Python library...)

Comment: Can you also share your code?

Comment: sure  @AhmetBurak - see below (although it is quite verbose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jq-only solution:

```
def objectify($header): 
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $header|length) as $i ({}; .[$header[$i]] = $in[$i] );

.data[0].values as $header
| .data |= (.[1:] | map(.values | objectify($header)) )
```

---

If you like nifty:

```
def objectify($header): with_entries(.key |= $header[.]) ;
```

So, if you want a two-liner:

```
.data[0].values as $header
| .data |= (.[1:] | map(.values | with_entries(.key |= $header[.])))
```

Comment: Uh, clever! It took me a while to understand why/how `.key |= $header[.]` works; nice two-liner!

Comment: You could even do a one-liner as `.data |= (. as [{values:$header}] | .[1:] | map(.values | with_entries(.key |= $header[.])))`, right? Or even more golfed `.data |= (map(.values) | . as [$header] | .[1:] | map(with_entries(.key |= $header[.])))`

Comment: Golf would warrant $h :-)

Comment: Hmm, it feels asymmetrical that `to_entries` works given an array, but because the keys are numeric indices, the to_entries output cannot directly be used as into to `from_entries`.

Comment: Asymmetrical they are, just as '+' on arrays is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different jq solution without `reduce`:

```
.data |= (
  map(.values)
  | first as $headers | del(first)
  | map(
    [ $headers, .]
    | transpose
    | map({(first): last})
    | add
  )
)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ColumnHeader1": "Row1Column1",
      "ColumnHeader2": "Row1Column2",
      "ColumnHeader3": "Row1Column3"
    },
    {
      "ColumnHeader1": "Row2Column1",
      "ColumnHeader2": "Row2Column2",
      "ColumnHeader3": "Row2Column3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or to rebuild the result object from scratch:

```
{
  data: (
    .data | map(.values)
    | first as $headers | del(first) 
    | map(
      [ $headers, .]
      | transpose
      | map({(first): last})
      | add
    )
  )
}
```

`first as $headers` could be rewritten as `. as [$headers]` or `.[0] as $headers`. `del(first)` could be replaced with `.[1:]`.

Comment: `map({(first): last})` -- nice!

Comment: @glennjackman this will not work for all cases. The proper solution would be `map({key:first, value:last)})|from_entries` (but for this particular question it works, so why not)

Comment: I had `map(. as [$key, $value] | {$key, $value}) | from_entries` and was happy to be reminded about first and last.

Comment: @glennjackman But note that `map(. as [$key, $value] | .)` only extracts the first two elements of the array (`.[0:2]`). `map(.[0:2] as [$key, $value] | .)` or `map(first as $key | .[1] as $value | .)` or `map(.[0] as $key | .[1] as $value | .)`. `last` only works here because the array contains exactly 2 elements :)

Answer (score 0):

(not very elegant) Answer

```
"""
Read a JSON file where the 1st item in array is a set of headers, and the other items are values.
Outputs a JSON file where the other items in array are transposed to use those headers.
"""
import json
from sys import argv

input_json=argv[1]
output_json=argv[2]

data = None
with open(input_json, "r") as infile:
    # returns JSON object as a dictionary
    data = json.load(infile)

headings = data["data"][0]['values']

new_rows = []
rows = len(data["data"])
for r in range(1, rows):
    row = data["data"][r]['values']
    new_row = dict()
    new_rows.append(new_row)
    for h in range(0, len(headings)):
        new_row[headings[h]] = row[h]

new_data = dict()
new_data["data"] = new_rows

with open(output_json, "w") as outfile:
    json_object = json.dumps(new_data, indent=2)
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

Hoping there is a better way with less code :)

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
d = {
   "data" : [
     { "values" : [ "ColumnHeader1", "ColumnHeader2", "ColumnHeader3" ]},
     { "values" : [ "Row1Column1", "Row1Column2", "Row1Column3" ]},
     { "values" : [ "Row2Column1", "Row2Column2", "Row2Column3" ]}
  ]
}


d = {"data": [{k: v for k, v in zip(d["data"][0]["values"], row["values"])} for row in d["data"][1:]]}
```

Outputs:

```
{'data': [{'ColumnHeader1': 'Row1Column1', 'ColumnHeader2': 'Row1Column2', 'ColumnHeader3': 'Row1Column3'}, {'ColumnHeader1': 'Row2Column1', 'ColumnHeader2': 'Row2Column2', 'ColumnHeader3': 'Row2Column3'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate all headings. I hope it helps.

```py
data = {
    "data": [
        {"values": ["ColumnHeader1", "ColumnHeader2", "ColumnHeader3"]},
        {"values": ["Row1Column1", "Row1Column2", "Row1Column3"]},
        {"values": ["Row2Column1", "Row2Column2", "Row2Column3"]},
    ]
}

data = data["data"]
headings = data[0]["values"]
rows = data[1:]
new_data = {"data":[dict(zip(headings, row["values"])) for row in rows]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for `jq` using `transpose` and `map`:

```bash
.data |= (map(.values) | transpose
  | map([{(.[0]): .[1:][]}]) | transpose
  | map(add)
)
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ColumnHeader1": "Row1Column1",
      "ColumnHeader2": "Row1Column2",
      "ColumnHeader3": "Row1Column3"
    },
    {
      "ColumnHeader1": "Row2Column1",
      "ColumnHeader2": "Row2Column2",
      "ColumnHeader3": "Row2Column3"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GLJDLGzDfE4)